# How to change a name of a function which is already defined? fe. writeNap to write (Pascal)

Tags: pascal

in our last class we defined a couple of functions and procedures in our unit file.

```
procedure WriteNap(const elo: string; const n: TNap; const uto: string);
begin
  Write(elo, Nap2Str(n), uto);
end;

function PredNap(const n: TNap): TNap;
begin
  case n of
    hetfo: PredNap := vasarnap;
    NemNap: PredNap := n;
  else  
    PredNap := Pred(n)
  end;
end;

function SuccNap(const n: TNap): TNap;
begin
  case n of
    NemNap: SuccNap := n;
  else
    SuccNap := Succ(n)
  end;
end;
```

I have to get rid of the word 'Nap' so that i can just use Pred, Write, Succ in the main program instead of PredNap etc... i tried to create another unit file which uses this unit and contains functions like Succ Pred... didnt really work out..

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare in somewhere in your file:

```
var Pred = Function (Const n:TNap):TNap;
```

And before you do anything in the body of your program, write:

```
Pred := @PredNap;
```

What this code does is, it creates a new function pointer with the same signature as your PredNap() and then assign the address of PredNap() to this pointer. So, whenever you call Pred() the actual function that gets called is PredNap(). Hope this helps.